# insert child element at last position

Tags: insert, position, lxml, element

Given a parent element, how do I insert a child element at the last position? So far, using an index of -1 places the child at the penultimate position:

```
In [22]: et.tostring(test)
Out[22]: b'<a><orange/><b>hee</b><apple/><pear/><b>haa</b></a>'
In [23]: test.insert(-1, et.Element('mango'))
In [24]: et.tostring(test)
Out[24]: b'<a><orange/><b>hee</b><apple/><pear/><mango/><b>haa</b></a>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the number of child elements (with `len()`) and use that as the index.

```python
from lxml import etree as et

test = et.fromstring('<a><orange/><b>hee</b><apple/><pear/><b>haa</b></a>')
test.insert(len(test), et.Element('mango')) 
print et.tostring(test, pretty_print=True)
```

Output:

```
<a>
  <orange/>
  <b>hee</b>
  <apple/>
  <pear/>
  <b>haa</b>
  <mango/>
</a>
```